# Coset state for non-abelian hidden subgroup problem

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, boolean-algebra, quantum-computation

On page 14 of his classic paper, [Quantum factoring, discrete logarithms
and the hidden subgroup problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0012084), Jozsa introduced a function $f$ for the non-abelian hidden subgroup representation of the graph isomorphism problem. I would like to quote him here.

> In our standard algorithm the function $f$ used to generate the random
>   coset state $|g_0 K \rangle$ is the efficiently computable $f : G \to
> > X$ where $X$ is the set of all matrices of size $2n \times 2n$ with
>   $0,1$ entries and $f(\Pi)$ is the matrix obtained by permuting the
>   rows and columns of $M_C$ by $\Pi$.

My question is:

1. How is $|g_0 K \rangle$ created? If we are checking two $n$ node graphs, how many qubits are required to construct the state?